# What ports need to be open for dnscmd.exe to operate?

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm currently working with the Microsoft DNS command line utility dnscmd.exe to automate DNS record deletion in our datacenter. To complete this automation I need to be able to access a domain controller on another network to delete records from it, but I am unsure what ports I need to open for this to work. I've already opened TCP/UDP port 53 from my server to the DC, but no dice. Any feedback would be much appreciated. I've included the command I'm issuing and the resulting error message:

#### dnscmd.exe abc.xyz.com /enumzones

```
DnssrvEnumZones() failed.
    Status = 1722 (0x000006ba)

Command Failed: RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE      1722 (000006ba)
```

Comment: I'm not positive, but I believe `dnscmd`, like a lot of other Microsoft management applications, [uses RPC dynamic port allocation](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/154596) for handshaking ... so it might not be as simple as opening a few standard/well-defined ports.

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to launch a packet capture on the source computer and filter the capture for the destination address. Then look at the capture results and determine what ports on the destination computer the source computer is attempting to communicate with. Additionally, are these DNS zones AD integrated? If so, do you have a local DNS server you can run the command on? If so, you can do that and let AD replicate the deletions to the remote DNS server(s).

Comment: I set up a Wireshark capture on the source server and I am starting to agree with Hopeless about the RPC dynamic port allocation. It seems to be initializing the call to port 135 (which I think is the RCP Endpoint Mapper) and then randomly selecting a port in the 50000+ range. Is there a specific range that I might need to open that RPC is dynamically selecting from?

Comment: With the help of Hopelessn00b you've discovered what the problem is. A little legwork on your part would go a long way to garner goodwill for yourself on this site. It's easy enough to Google for RPC dynamic ports and learn what ports you'll need to work with in order to get the command working across your firewalls. - https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=rpc+dynamic+ports

Comment: Are you sure that it wouldn't be easier to just establish a VPN of some sort to the destination network?